# When the co-author of a potential paper is not responsible

Tags: mathematics, postdocs, paper-submission, mentoring, responsibilities

I am a math postdoc and my young mentor is unfortunately a lazy person. I have prepared a manuscript 4 months ago and still no news about revision of that from the mentor. I do not know what can I do. Is it good to find someone else to help me to finish this paper? Sometimes the unknown referee suggest some ideas to improve the paper, Can I submit it to a journal and waiting for referee report?

Comment: If the mentor is a co-author then you need their permission to publish it, but you don't actually need additional cooperation.

Comment: I hope you talked to your mentor about this a few times since you gave him the manuscript 4 month ago?

Comment: Responsible or responsive?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is the same as for 50% of the other questions on this website: *Talk to your adviser*. Find out what the hold-up is, how you can help, what other roles you could take on in the lab to free him from work that holds up his side of the collaboration. *Communicate* about what your issues are.